# How to measure the 'user' time execution of a function in Linux and Windows

Tags: c, profiling

If I have a function *foo* which I would like to profile its "user" time (remove kernel or other processes time), how can I measure it in code (C/C++)?

I know of the following functions:

**Windows**

1. QueryPerformanceCounter
2. GetProcessTimes

**Linux**

1. gettimeofday
2. times
3. clock

Are there more ways? Each provide a different 'view' of time and non really provide accurate results.

Comment: i don't know about windows, but i've used timeofday on linux and it has been very accurate. it's also the norm on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix-like systems `getrusage` is what you're looking for. Specifically with the `RUSAGE_SELF` option. The user time will be in the `ru_utime` field in `struct rusage`. `ru_stime` counts system time.

Answer (score 2):

The best way on Linux is as following: (As extracted and modified a bit from the Linux kernel **perf_event_open** man page)

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>

long
perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
            int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
{
    int ret;

    ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
               group_fd, flags);
    return ret;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    long long count;
    int fd;

    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS;
    pe.disabled = 1;
    pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
    pe.exclude_hv = 1;

    fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

    printf("Measuring instruction count for this printf\n");

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
    read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));

    printf("Used %lld instructions\n", count);

    close(fd);
}
```